# Getting only n Number of values per Index with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a flowing Series:

```
               Data
Level1 Level2
A        A1      10
         A2      11
         A3      12
         A4      13
B        B1      14
         B2      15
         B3      16
         B4      17
         B5      18
```

I want to only get the first three entries per Level 2 while I leave the level 1 intact.

```
             Data
Level1 Level2
A        A1      10
         A2      11
         A3      12
B        B1      14
         B2      15
         B3      16
```

I tried with iloc or loc or indexslice but I am not using the syntax right. I am new to pandas. This is aan assignment in a course and I have spent more hours trying out but I cant figure it out.

Comment: There is correct indentation , because MultiIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) by first level:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0).head(3)
```

If use `pandas 0.24+`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Level1').head(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.groupby('Level1').head(3).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Please try to add some more information on how you arrived at this answer, and give some indication why this solution is correct, see [answer].